# MySQL - Return Distinct Rows and Count of their Duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL isn't my strong suit, can someone recommend an efficient query for pulling all distinct values from a column and counting all duplicates of each distinct value?

So for example the following table

```
s_ip
---------   
10.1.25.4
10.8.25.8
10.1.25.4
10.1.25.4
10.8.25.8
10.1.48.1
10.1.25.4
```

Would return

```
s_ip      | Count
----------|------
10.1.25.4 | 4
10.8.25.8 | 2
10.1.48.1 | 1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s_ip , COUNT(*) as count FROM table_name GROUP BY (s_ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
s_ip, count(*) as `count`
from table
group by s_ip
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8463f5/1)**